# Register model admin list in admin.py

Tags: python, django-models, django-admin

I have model that I display in my admin page

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from jet.filters import DateRangeFilter
from .models import KPIReport
# from date_range_filter import DateRangeFilter
from django.utils.html import format_html
# from rangefilter.filter import DateRangeFilter
# Register your models here.



@admin.register(KPIReport)
class KPIReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):


    list_display = ('Date','Item_SKU','Account','Country','Sessions','Session_Pct','Page_Views','Page_Views_Pct','Buy_Box_Pct','Units_Ordered','Unit_Session_Pct','Ordered_Product_Sales','Total_Order_Items','Sales_Rank','Actual_Sales','Selling_Price','Reviews','Camel', 'Notes')
    list_filter = (('Date', DateRangeFilter),'ItemSKU','Account','Country')
    search_fields = ('Date','ASIN','ItemSKU','Account','Country','Selling_Price')
    list_editable = ('Notes',)
```

I would like to produce a second table to view in my admin that filters the same model by account. CHG in this case

```
class KPI_CHG(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = KPIReport

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(KPI_CHG, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(Account='CHG')

    list_display = ('Date','Item_SKU','Account','Country','Sessions','Session_Pct','Page_Views','Page_Views_Pct','Buy_Box_Pct','Units_Ordered','Unit_Session_Pct','Ordered_Product_Sales','Total_Order_Items','Sales_Rank','Actual_Sales','Selling_Price','Reviews','Camel', 'Notes')
    list_filter = (('Date', DateRangeFilter),'ItemSKU','Country')
    search_fields = ('Date','ASIN','ItemSKU','Country','Selling_Price')
    list_editable = ('Notes',)
```

I Know I have the filter where i can drop down and accomplish this. The users still want to be able to go to a version of this list that only contains objects from account "CHG"

using 1.10 and python 2.7

How can I view this second table, or is my approach incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is using a proxy model with a custom manager
[Link to Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). This is necessary because you can only register a model once. With the custom Manager you can work on the same databasetable, but with a slightly different behavior

In your case you would have to do the following in models.py:

```
class CHG_Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(Account='CHG')

class KPI_CHG(KPIReport):
    objects = CHG_Manager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

And in admin.py:

```
from .models import KPIReport, KPI_CHG
@admin.register(KPI_CHG)
class KPI_CHGAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Date','Item_SKU','Account','Country','Sessions','Session_Pct','Page_Views','Page_Views_Pct','Buy_Box_Pct','Units_Ordered','Unit_Session_Pct','Ordered_Product_Sales','Total_Order_Items','Sales_Rank','Actual_Sales','Selling_Price','Reviews','Camel', 'Notes')
    list_filter = (('Date', DateRangeFilter),'ItemSKU','Country')
    search_fields = ('Date','ASIN','ItemSKU','Country','Selling_Price')
    list_editable = ('Notes',)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am trying to get it work. I added the model under the line  def get_quaryset(self):